# Xcode UITest: How to assert the label has bold text?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, xcode-ui-testing, assertion

I'm having a button to change the normal text to bold text in the label of my UIView. In UITesting, How to assert that the normal text changed to bold text when i pressed the button?

```
  let app = XCUIApplication()
  let label = app.staticTexts["myLabel"]
  app.buttons["Bold"].tap()
  XCTAssertEqual(label.value as! String, "Hello")
```

Comment: show us your code

Comment: added the code for asserting normal text, but how to assert for bold?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it. As XCUITest is functional test, if you want to
assert visual requirements like font, colour, you should write a unit test insteads.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to acess UI components (or whatever members of `UIKit`, including `UIFont`) over `XCUIElementAttributes` protocol (what is used for passing accessibility information for `XCTest` environment).

However you are free to write whatever you want in `accessibilityValue` or `accessibilityLabel` properties and read them afterwards. For me it's the only way to get round `XCTest` limitations when needed (however it will corrupt accessibility user experience, so you should take it into account)